# N gravity simulator using Pymunk

Tags: python, pygame, simulator, gravity, pymunk

I am using Pymunk to make a gravity simulator. The problem I am facing is the units. For example, if I want to define the constant G for the vector Force, how do I do it? I need some sort of conversion table for this. I already tested 9.8 using the command "space.gravity(0, -9.8), and it falls very slowly, meaning pymunk is not set on meters and seconds. How can I use approximate values?

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Pymunk documentation](http://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/overview.html#mass-weight-and-units):

> Mass, weight and units
>
> Sometimes users of Pymunk can be confused as to what unit everything
>   is defined in. For example, is the mass of a Body in gram of kilogram?
>   Pymunk is unit-less and does not care which unit you use. If you pass
>   in seconds to a function expecting time, then your time unit is
>   seconds. If you pass in pixels to functions that expect a distance,
>   then your unit of distance is pixels.
>
> Then derived units are just a combination of the above. So in the case
>   with seconds and pixels the unit of velocity would be pixels / second.

"Meters" likely has no meaning in your display space.  "Seconds" is a unit that you drive with your implementation delays.  It's all a matter of what interactions you build into your code.